# Are subviews automatically added as listeners to their superview's UIGestureRecognizers?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a swipe gesture attached to a UIView that doesn't seem to be registering when the swipe is on top of it's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say A is the root UIView which you want to receive swipes, and B is a subview of A that you don't really want to receive swipes.

- if you do not want to receive any gestures on B, you can userInteractionEnabled = false on it
- if you still want to receive some gestures on B (but not a swipe)

you must subclass B so that you can implement this method, and implement this method in B

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:UISwipeGestureRecognizer]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

You can also see how you may get a wide range of functionality from implementing gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:

Answer (score 0):

One of solution is to check is gesture point inside your subview or not,
there is a useful C function:

```
/* Return true if `point' is contained in `rect', false otherwise. */
bool CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point)
```

that you can use like this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
  return CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, [touch locationInView:self.view]);;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions should work, but a potentially easier one is to set `subview.userInteractionEnabled = false` in the subview if it doesn't have its own event handlers.